# [CRA][Vscode] Absolute Import not work when create new file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, cra

I got this problem in VS code, only within this project.
When I created a new file, I can't use Absolute Import Path, I have to restart the VS Code or re-run `npm start`

It is time-consuming when I have to re-run the project or restart VS code every time when I create a new file.
Please help me out
Here is my tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```